# Newtonsoft.Json validation: enforce a specific set of values for a property

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have an API project on [.NET Core 3.1](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) configured to use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

`Startup.cs`

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // [...]

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    // [...]
}
```

`Data.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace MyNS
{
    [JsonObject]
    public class MyData
    {
        [JsonProperty("query", Required=Required.Always)]
        public Query Query { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("limit")]
        public int Limit { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        [JsonProperty("props", Required=Required.Always)]
        public List<Prop> Props { get; set; }
    }

    public class Prop
    {
        // Allowed values should be only ("key1" and "key2"). Other strings or types should fail validation
        [JsonProperty("key", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Key { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MyController.cs`

```cs
// [...]
[Route("test")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Test(MyData data)
{
    return Json(data);
}
// [...]
```

On a specific property (Prop.Key in this example) I need the validation to fail if the value is different from a specific set values (eg "key1" and "key2"). Is it possible to configure a validation like this in `Newtonsoft.Json`?

Comment: Don't use strings, use an `enum` instead.

Comment: You may look at `IValidatableObject` interface

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, it seems that using `enum` instead of `string` does the trick